# Passing zip code in params to use in geo distance filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the thinking sphinx gem and it works. There is one last part I can't figure out. The current setup detects the current users latitude and longitude based on their zip code attribute and includes it in the search options.

I would like to make a slight change. Keep the same format but if a zip code is passed in the params using the search form `/searches?utf8=✓&zip_code=10001` that it would use the params zip code instead if its present.

2 reasons why I need this change:

- So non-registered users can perform a search
- So registered users can search different areas

It seems to be this line that I need to add to:

```
        :geo => [current_user.latitude * Math::PI / 180.0, current_user.longitude * Math::PI / 180.0]
```

Search controller:

```
  def index
    @search = Search.new

    if location = Location.find_by_zip_code(params[:search])
        latitude  = location.latitude * Math::PI / 180 
        longitude = location.longitude * Math::PI / 180 

        locations = Location.search( 
          :geo   => [latitude, longitude], 
          :with  => {:geodist => 0.0..100_000.0}, 
          :order => 'geodist ASC',
          :per_page => 5_000
        ) 
        @users = User.where(zip_code: locations.map(&:zip_code))

          else
            @users = User.search(params[:query],
            :conditions => {:ethnicity => params[:ethnicity], :gender => params[:gender]},
            :with => {:age => (params[:min_age].to_i)..(params[:max_age].to_i), :geodist => 0.0..100_000.0},
            :geo => [current_user.latitude * Math::PI / 180.0, current_user.longitude * Math::PI / 180.0],
            :order => 'geodist ASC', :without => {:user_id => current_user.id})      


        end
```